# Escaping ^ symbol in exp_send when using awk

Tags: tcl, expect

So I need to pass an `Awk` command from an expect script to identify a `eth` interface containing a particular octet, I am currently doing,

```
exp_send "ip addr show | awk -F: '/\^\[0-9\]/ {dev=\$2} /inet .*\\.227/ {print dev; exit}' \r"
```

The problem is with the `/\^\[0-9\]` part, a single `\` is not working and I also tried adding `\\` which also doesn't seem to work.

Also tried wrapping the entire `awk` contents within `{..}` which too didn't work.

```
exp_send "ip addr show | awk -F: {/^\[0-9\]/ {dev=\$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}} \r"
```

Any leads on how to fix this would be appreciated.

---

Update, from the suggestions from @whjm, I enabled the internal debugger options as

```
exp_internal -f /tmp/debug 1
exp_send "ip addr show | awk -F: '/^\[0-9]/ {dev=\$2} /inet .*\\.227/ {print dev; exit}'\r"
exp_internal 0
```

produces information as

```
send: sending "ip addr show | awk -F: '/^[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'\r" to { exp13 }
```

and the console capture on the end device produces,

```
$ send: sending "ip addr show | awk -F: '/[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'\r" to { exp13 }
ip addr show | awk -F: '/[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'
```

The `^` character is some-how lost while sending.

Comment: Please show enough of the script to reproduce the problem. Also, changing the input to point at a file instead will help others reproduce it.

Comment: @merlin2011: I would have provided it, if I have the way, In general the `expect` scripts are not easily re-created, was probably looking for a general thumb rule which applies to escaping meta characters in `tcl`/`expect`

Comment: The 1st `send: sending` message did have `^` but the 2nd did not. Weird.

Comment: Mind giving the exact `ssh` command you `spawn`ed?

Comment: @whjm: Is there anything suspicious I should look for there? Again, it is well structured code, the `ssh` procedures are abstracted, I need to go through a bunch of function calls to see the actual options used.

Comment: I was thinking if `-e` was specified for `ssh` but that would not make any difference here. Forget about it. The only other thing I can think of for now is the output of `stty -a` on the remote host after ssh login, just to check if somewhere `^` is configured as a special char for the *pty*.

Comment: @whjm: so you like to me to add `stty -a` right after the `ssh` call?

Comment: Yes, `exp_send "stty -a\r"` after ssh and get the output.

Comment: @whjm: It produced an output as `speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 209; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>` Could this be an issue?

Comment: Did not see anything suspicious.

Comment: Replace `exp_send` with `interact` and see if you can input the `^` char manually.

Comment: @whjm: A million thanks for your time. Was able to get it working by using an alternate `grep` command without needing `^`.

Comment: yes there are workarounds. still curious about what's the real problem. :)

Comment: @whjm: Am accepting your answer for the quality time you spent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to use double quotes (e.g. to include some `$var` in it):

```
exp_send "ip addr show | awk -F: '/^\[0-9]/ {dev=\$2} /inet .*\\.227/ {print dev; exit}'\r"
```

---

In the Tcl language:

1. `^` and `'` are not special.
2. `{` is not special in double quotes (`"..."`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Similar to my comment to glenn's answer above, your logic makes the command appear as `ip addr show | awk -F: '/[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'` on the end device. Again the `^` is missing which is incorrect for me.

Comment: Tcl/Expect itself would not discard the `^` char. Could you `expect -d /your/script.exp` and paste the output?

Comment: It is not a straight forward `expect` script, am using the library on a `tcl` file. So the context is the script runs in the test bed, `ssh` into the end-device and and passing this `exp_send` to get the `ethN` interface containing the octet

Comment: you can put some statements between `exp_internal -f /tmp/debug 1` and `exp_internal 0`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more, haven't use `exp_internal` before. Where do I add it?

Comment: Like this: `exp_internal -f /tmp/debug 1; exp_send "ip ... | awk ..."; expect "something"; ...; exp_internal 0`

Comment: Just a noob question. You just gave an example of having `expect "something"`? or want it to be there as part of the command?

Comment: I mean you put an `expect ...` command after `exp_send` if at all possible.

Comment: So I suppose it is optional, plese refer my update in the question to see the debug information

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the **outer** quotes you need to be concerned about. Try

```
exp_send {ip addr show | awk -F: '/^[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'}
# .......^ using Tcl non-substituting quotes, so inside stuff does not need escaping
exp_send "\r"
```

Comment: Thanks glenn for the answer, when sent this way, the command appears as `ip addr show | awk -F: '/[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.227/ {print dev; exit}'` in the end device. Observe that `^` is not present !

Comment: How do you connect to the end device? It is telnet?

Comment: It is done via `ssh` just have a look the comments in the other answer to see what is happening :)

Comment: The carat symbol is not normally special at all, in expect or in awk. Either your connection protocol is doing something with it, or the remote terminal is somehow eating it. Try escaping it with a backslash (`/\^[0-9]/`), or try doubling it (`/^^[0-9]/`), or try sending it as a hex character (`/\x5e[0-9]/`)

Comment: Thanks glenn, unfortunately none of the suggested options worked. I used an alternate way to deal with this, a `grep` command without `^`